# How to excute docker exec commande inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, exec

I execute a command inside a docker container :

```
docker exec -i nullmailer sendmail -f username@gmail.com
```

The container response is :

> the docker command does not exist.

How to execute docker exec commande inside a docker container ?

Thanks in advance for any responses

Comment: In order to run docker cli from within container you need to have it installed on docker image from which you're running the container. Why exactly are you running a command from container and not from host?

Comment: I have installed https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/nullmailer/ image. The purpose is to send a mail from a php container to  nullmailer container. One way to achieve this, is to run this command in the php container.

Answer (score 1):

If your containers are running on the same host, you can run docker commands inside the container, by exposing the docker socket to the container.

To achieve this, when running the container, mount the docker.sock as such:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

Now you can execute docker commands from within the container.